How to serialize and exclude specific fields with class-transformer in NestJS?
I am developing an API using NestJS and I have an endpoint that returns a list of users along with some pagination information. Here is the relevant part of my controller:
@HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
@Get()
async getAllUsers(@Query() userQuery: UserQueryDto) {
  const users = await this.userService.findAllByFilter(userQuery);
  return users;
}

The response is structured as follows, defined in UsersResponse:
class UsersResponse {
  data: Users[];
  pagination: Pagination
}

class Pagination {
  total: number;
  page: number;
  limit: number;
  totalPages: number;
}

class Users {
  id: string;
  hash: string;
  email: string;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

I want to serialize the Users data using class-transformer and exclude the hash field when returning the response. How can I achieve this in the most efficient way within the NestJS framework? Is there a decorator or a specific method in class-transformer that allows selectively excluding fields from the serialized object?

You can use the @Exclude decorator.
import { Exclude } from 'class-transformer';

export class UserEntity {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;

  @Exclude()
  password: string;

  constructor(partial: Partial<UserEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}

Reference

But what if I have an array of users.
